# How to use 'Bind Variables' in a 'Dynamic Query ' when the exact number of variables are not known

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a procedure in which I'm using `Dynamic SQL`(variable `actual_query`) and I'm generating this query based on the input parameter `i_tables` which is a concatenation of the name of some tables. It has one of these forms:

1. All tables `test_table1,test_table2.
2. Nothing. So `NULL` will pass to the procedure.

I've read about `Bind variable` and the significant role it has in preventing `injection` and improving `performance` and I want to use it in my procedure.The problem is that I do not know how exactly I should change my procedure to use them specially in this situation when `number of variables are not known.` When you know the exact number of variables, you write `execute immediate actual_query using var1,var2` and you know you will exactly have 2 variables.

```
create or replace procedure bind_variable_test(i_tables varchar2,
                                               i_cid    number,
                                               o_result out sys_refcursor) is
actual_query varchar2(1000) := '';
begin

-- this is the base query   
actual_query := 'select * 
            from z_test_a t1 
              inner join z_test_b t2 
               on t1.id = t2.id';
            
-- check input parameter " i_tables "   
if i_tables like '%test_table1%' then
  actual_query := actual_query || ' ' || 'inner join test_table1 t3 on ' ||
                     't3.id = t1.id ' || 'and t3.cid = ' || i_cid;
end if;

if i_tables like '%test_table2%' then
  actual_query := actual_query || ' ' || 'inner join test_table2 t4 on ' ||
                     't4.id = t1.id ' || 'and t4.cid = ' || i_cid;
end if;


-- debug results
dbms_output.put_line(actual_query); 

-- execute    
open o_result for actual_query;
end;
```

After reading `DBMS_SQL` manual , I tried to edit my code and I did this:

```
create or replace procedure z_bind_variable_test(i_tables varchar2,
                                             i_cid    number,
                                             o_result out sys_refcursor)       is
actual_query varchar2(1000) := '';
c            pls_integer;
begin
-- this is the base query
actual_query := 'select * 
              from z_test_a t1 
               inner join z_test_b t2  
            on t1.c_num = t2.c_num ';

-- check input parameter " i_tables "
if i_tables like '%test_table1%' then
  actual_query := actual_query || ' ' || 'inner join test_table1 t3 ' ||
                'on t3.C_NUM = t1.C_NUM ' || 'and t3.cid = :c_id';
end if;

if i_tables like '%test_table2%' then
  actual_query := actual_query || ' ' || 'inner join test_table2 t4 ' ||
                'on t4.C_NUM = t1.C_NUM ' || 'and t4.cid = :c_id ';
end if;

-- get cursor
c := dbms_sql.open_cursor();

-- parse the SQL
dbms_sql.parse(c, actual_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

-- using bind variables
dbms_sql.bind_variable(c, ':c_id', i_cid);

-- execute
o_result := dbms_sql.execute(c);

-- close the cursor
dbms_sql.close_cursor(c);
end;
```

But it just won't work! I want to learn how to use bind variables correctly but don't know whether I'm in the right path.

Update : The error I get is `PLS-00382:Expression is of wrong type`. And the problem is for this part `o_result := dbms_sql.execute(c);`

Comment: and can you tell us what problems do you have and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @miracle173.I've changed my code to make it simpler and I've also added some notes to make my point clearer. I want to be able to write neat and professional codes and one of the ways is to ask good questions . Thanks for your concern.

Comment: you still didn't describe your problem. In a comment you mention that you " have problem in this part of the code : o_result := dbms_sql.execute(c);". But you didn't tell us what kind of problem you encounter. Did you get an error message? If so, what error message?

Comment: @miracle173 . I updated my question and added the error code . hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DBMS_SQL`.

The fine manual has plenty of examples.

## Sample

TBD

Comment: **T**o **B**e **D**etermined (TBD) is a place holder for actual code example because I havent had my morning coffee. In the meantime, I leave it as an exercise for the student to read all about `DBMS_SQL` in the fine manual.

Comment: I've changed my code after reading the manuals and related question . The problem still remains . I was wondering if you could take a look at my new code .

Comment: Did you spit out the query *before* you parsed it? What problem/error code?

Comment: I've changed my code and I used dbms_sql as you said . but I'm not sure whether I'm in the correct path! I have problem in this part of the code : o_result := dbms_sql.execute(c);

Comment: While it is true that the fine manual has plenty of examples, there is none (at least none that I was able to find) that addresses the problem of the OP. In addition, there seems to be no documented functionality in `dbms_sql` that allows to determine the number of bind variables in an arbitrary SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

split the variable and fetch each element. That is, use a cursor

Comment: Thanks but could you please give an example? Cause could not follow.